# Getting a user ID and a process group ID from a task_struct and a pid_namespace

Tags: process, linux-kernel, userid, process-group

I'm trying to modify Linux kernel and I need to get the user ID and the process group ID from a `task_struct` and a `pid_namespace`. Although I searched their definitions in the source code, I couldn't find any global variables or functions (maybe I am missing because of the lack of the comments in codes) to access them.

Is there a method to get those inside the kernel space since I can not use user-space functions like `getuid()`, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use `task_struct->cred->uid` or `task_struct->real_cred->uid`. That being said, I have not tested this and this is just from a cursory reading of LXR (include/linux/sched.h line 1508 and include/linux/cred.h line 127).

If you want the PGID, try `pid_vnr(task_pgrp(task_struct))`. This code is from kernel/sys.c line 990.

Comment: thank you. If you know can you answer for pid_namespace?

Comment: From my quick perusal (and I am by no means a kernel developer), it doesn't appear that PID namespaces have any users or groups associated with them. See http://lwn.net/Articles/531419/

Comment: actually I am changing fs/proc/base.c the function has_pid_permission. In default one they used pid->hide_pid, pid->pid_gid (pid is a pid_namespace pointer). I thought pid_namespace is a special structure for a process to hold just its pid values, so it should contain pgid,uid etc. Am I correct? Although it has pid_gid ( thread group, or process group not so sure), hide_pid, last_pid(?) variables, It doesn't have any uid type variable. Actually what i want to do is just compare the current process with the task. I thought that function does the same.

Comment: @JoelC I tried to use task_struct->real_cred->uid, and i gets error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘const struct cred’?

Comment: @Sohaib please make a new question and post the code you're using.

Comment: @JoelC thank you )) https://stackoverflow.com/q/61211757/5688267