# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘const struct cred’

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want to understand this error. Printing UID of a process, code:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "User ID = %d\n", (task)->cred->uid);
```

The error:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘const struct cred’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward: the compiler is telling you that the type `struct cred` is incomplete. In other words, the compiler does not know its definition, and therefore it does not know whether there is a `uid` field or where in the struct the field is located. Therefore it cannot compile that `->uid`.

To fix this, simply include a correct definition of `struct cred`:

```
#include <linux/cred.h>
```